# How does one load draw more or less current compared to another load?

Tags: transistors, current, load

What got me asking is I'm currently studying about NPN transistors whose base draws very little current.

Why does the base draw so little current, lets say compared to the collector?
What differentiates the base of the NPN transistor from an LED when it comes to drawing current?
Or on a more general way, how does one load draw more/less current compared to another load when the same current is entering them (assuming same input current)?

Comment: because the same current *doesn't* enter. The concept of *impedance* was invented to account for this.

Comment: If the "same current is entering them" then there is no party balloon and no ticker-tape; the same current in both is pretty much a dismal transistor.

Comment: The base of an NPN draws little current if you operate the transistor properly. Connect it the wrong way and it will draw so much current it will destroy itself. I suggest you study some basic textbooks about electonics and enlighten yourself that way instead of asking here where some research into the subject is expected from the person asking the question.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does the base draw so little current, lets say compared to the collector?

Because there's usually a resistor in series with the base (or the emitter) to limit the current through the base.

> What differentiates the base of the NPN transistor from an LED when it comes to drawing current?

Only their forward voltage drops.

> Or on a more general way, how does one load draw more/less current compared to another load when the same current is entering them (assuming same input current)?

Ya lost me there...

Answer (score 0):

Because that's what a transistor does:

[image]

The very property that makes a transistor so useful causes the base and collector currents to be different.  This is the point of the transistor gain.

For example, with a NPN transistor that has a gain of 50, 1 mA of current into the base allows the collector to sink up to 50 mA of current.  According to Kirkchoff, you can't pile up current, so these currents have to come out someplace.  That someplace is the emitter, which in this example will have 51 mA flowing out of it.

If the base and collector currents were always the same, transistors would be really boring, and of little use.